Reassembling RAID 5 when 1 disk has been overwritten
I was having trouble with my Ubuntu system that was running a Raid 5 setup with 4x4Tb drives: /dev/sda[1234]. The OS was installed on /dev/sde.
So I decided it was time to do a clean install of the OS.. And here is where my stupidity came in.. I accidentally installed Ubuntu on /dev/sda. I've now re-installed to /dev/sde but I'm having trouble re-assembling the raid
I had backed up my /etc folder but again stupidity, I backed it up to my raid thinking I wouldn't have any issues reassembling it
I know the data on /dev/sda is lost.. I'm just wondering how much I can recover with the other 3 drives.
In general, i get the following error on most attempts. If I change the order of the disks, then i get this error for the first drive in the list
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 has no superblock - assembly aborted

I've tried to assemble a number of different ways but always hitting an issue
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1

I've thought that maybe i just assemble with the 3 good disks and then I could add /dev/sda after but I get that same error
sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1

I even thought maybe I could create a new raid 5 with /dev/sda and then add the others in but that didn't seem to work either
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda1 missing missing missing
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --re-add /dev/sdb1
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1

Output of fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000DM000-1F21
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EEFB7529-8BC9-2C46-B529-DFEC565586AE

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 7814037134 7814035087  3.6T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000DM000-1F21
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6559C610-734A-4978-B52D-FB8561D8CB6E

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.6T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdc: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000DM000-1F21
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0F3B652A-6AB8-4A98-B91B-F50C1373347A

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.6T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdd: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000DM000-1F21
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E50D44A3-67C3-43AD-AD96-D11A66A0DCC8

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.6T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sde: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: OCZ-SOLID3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6D5DF417-2864-48FC-83DC-A1E42EF3DE9C

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sde1     2048   2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/sde2  2203648 234438655 232235008 110.7G Linux filesystem

Output from mdadm --examine /dev/sd*
/dev/sda:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 1d5b33b8:7c4c31ce:c694e0b0:d0335928
           Name : mediaserver:0  (local to host mediaserver)
  Creation Time : Wed Sep 25 21:14:48 2024
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7813770895 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 11720655360 KiB (10.92 TiB 12.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 15aba39b:06fdb0ba:3b3fe20f:d646646e

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Sep 25 21:14:48 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : 650e8daa - correct
         Events : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A... ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb1.
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdc1.
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdd1.
/dev/sde:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :    234441647 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sde1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sde2.


sd[abcd] letters can change, did you verify which was which every time? Your create attempt (using the bad drive first, then adding all others to it), shouldn't even work that way, but if it did, would have wiped all your drives. Do any of these drives still have metadata? mdadm --examine /dev/sd*

I get the no recogniseable superblock error when I run mdadm --examine /dev/sd*. I've add the output to the bottom of the description. The output from /dev/sda is because of the 'create' attempt I tried

I also updated description that i don't have access to the old /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf file because of my stupidity again :(

So, we don't have metadata (the one on sda is a red herring you created yourself). Not much else to go on. It's pretty much not possible to answer based on the information provided. It might still be recoverable regardless - depends what actually happened to these other drives and why their metadata was wiped. Make full copies of the drives and/or use overlays. Then try to get anywhere with generic advice on mdadm --create. Without metadata you'll have to guess everything - data offset, drive order, chunk size, …

I would first remove the "deleted" disk. Make sure you know which one it is, power down the server and completely unplug the device. Then check again with mdadm --examine

I would do the following:

first identify the deleted disk. Use fdisk or some other tool to make sure. (mdadm --examine is the best for this since you can see the device) If you have installed a clean OS in it as you said, take the disk out and try booting in another machine.
You have to be SURE that this disk is identified. I would just unplug this disk for now.

Use mdadm to check for the disks that have recognizable superblocks. I would write down the device names to make sure. If the three remaining disks don´t have recognizable superblocks, you are in trouble. You need the three of them to reasemble the RAID. make sure you remove the failed (deleted) disk from the array: mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sd?? (make sure it's the correct disk you remove).

If you have three disks, just run the reasemble command (mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1). If you only have two, bad luck. Nothing to recover.

Delete the content of the deleted disk. Try deleting the partitions with fdisk. If this does not work, use dd and delete the first GB of the disk. In this way you will be able to add the disk again to the array. (probably it works without deleting it, I have not tried).

Add the new disk to the array. mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sd??

Last possibility. No superblocks are seen: try to reassemble with create: mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 and replace the missing device with the word missing.

If you reach this point, you will need to recreate the mdadm.conf file and update the initial RAM FS.



Thanks @LincolnP though I don't think this will help. I don't currently have a RAID setup. I have 4 drives that used to be in a RAID5 setup. One of those drives has been wiped by accident and the other 3 drives do not have any superblocks
My understanding is that mdadm --create will wipe the drives and i'll lose my data

Thanks to the input
I wasn't able to recover.. In the end I ran mdadm --create which created /dev/md0 but I wasn't able to mount it as it didn't have a superblock or partition, I ended up reformatting it with mkfs.ext4 and I could then mount it
